# PHP regular expressions and XML

Tags: php, regex

I have an [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) database of 17000 records that are not well formed. The problem with the XML is that the attributes are not in quotes ("").

My script collects only one record.

The problem is to put the attribute values within quotes.

So if I have a string like:

```
$str = "This is a test id=abc> string";
$str1 = '="';
$str2 = str_replace("=", $str1, $str);
```

My problem is to to get the attribute value within the quotes (`id="abc">`). I tried using regular expressions, but that didn't work.

Comment: Can you show the RegEx that you tried? Maybe we can fix it?

Comment: When you say "not well formed", do you mean it simply fails to be interpreted as valid XML.  I know that's what the statement means, but I just want to check that's what YOU mean.  If so it sounds like a hiding to nothing.  There may be a regex that will solve your immediate problem, but the smallest change may well break it again.  Your best bet is to go back to the source of the XML and get the generator to fix it.

Comment: I recommend to use `$dom_html = new DomDocument(); $dom_html->loadHTML($html_source);` then you can get the attributes easily or if you want you can save the HTML as standard HTML string

Comment: @javad: won't help. PHP DOM is extremely picky about malformed HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$string = "This is a test id=abc> string";
$replace = preg_replace('/=([\w]+)/i', '="$1"', $string );

echo $replace ;
//This is a test id="abc"> string
?>
```

http://ideone.com/OurhHV